# Updating a user record in Node js + Express + Passport + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

Ok, so I've been struggling with this for hours and can't figure out how to get it to work.

I followed this tutorial to completion on setting up nodejs with mongodb, express and passport:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local
It works great, except now I want to use the authenticated session to allow the user to create a display name via a form.

I'm stumped because I can't figure out how to use the route/passport/session method to update the user record in mongodb via a POST request.

My question relates to the 'Process Update Profile' block of code below. I'm trying to use the user.update function to add a displayname to my user record. I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: user is not defined
at Object.handle (/vagrant/new/app/routes.js:65:9)
at next_layer (/vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
at Object.isLoggedIn [as handle] (/vagrant/new/app/routes.js:115:16)
at next_layer (/vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
at Route.dispatch (/vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
at /vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24
at Function.proto.process_params (/vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
at next (/vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
at next_layer (/vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:77:14)
at next_layer (/vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:14)
at next_layer (/vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:14)
at Route.dispatch (/vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
at /vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24
at Function.proto.process_params (/vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
at next (/vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
at next (/vagrant/new/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
```

I can see that user isn't passed to the function I'm using, but I can't figure out what the correct method should be - or if I'm approaching this the right way at all.
See code below:

```
// app/routes.js
module.exports = function(app, passport) { 
// =====================================
// HOME PAGE (with login links) ========
// =====================================
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs'); // load the index.ejs file
});

//... some code (login, signup methods) omitted for brevity ...

// =====================================
// UPDATE PROFILE =================
// =====================================
app.get('/updateprofile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('updateprofile.ejs', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});

// =====================================
// PROCESS UPDATE PROFILE=======================
// =====================================
// process the update profile form
app.post('/updateprofile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    user.update({_id: req.session.passport.user}, {
        displayName: req.body.displayName 
    }, function(err, numberAffected, rawResponse) {
       console.log('new profile update error');
    });
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});

// =====================================
// PROFILE SECTION =====================
// =====================================
// we will want this protected so you have to be logged in to visit
// we will use route middleware to verify this (the isLoggedIn function)
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});
```

};
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

```
// if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

// if they aren't redirect them to the home page
res.redirect('/');
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this line at the top of your routes.js file:

```
var user = require('../app/models/user'); //i get the address of user model in the link you give, but in general it should be the user model address.
```

because when you use update function, the `user` in code below, should be the name of your MongoDB Model.

```
user.update({_id: req.session.passport.user}, {
        displayName: req.body.displayName 
    },function(err, numberAffected, rawResponse) {
       console.log('new profile update error');
    });
```

the correct query for update is:

```
{_id: req.session.passport.user.id}
```

if you want to find a user based on it's id, then you should query with the user's id.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the error - however, my database still doesn't update with the new value for display name. is the update function calling an update to mongodb or just the user instance I just created?

Comment: Also, here's my schema in /app/models/user: 

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
        displayName  : String
    },
    google           : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String,
        displayName  : String
    }

});

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed now! I also made one other mistake - I was rendering based on req.user, which is still the unchanged record from the POST.

Comment: @user1871200, i'm glad your problem solved. 
oh, yes you're right!